# Responsive Div with microTiles organized with Flexbox

Tags: html, css

```css
#theTeamWrapper {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 background-image: url('https://www.kuboland.com/integra/images/bgTexture-01.png');
 background-size:cover;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 padding-top: 140px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#megaWrapper {
  width:90%;
  height:auto;
  background-color: ;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-content: flex-start;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#tile {
  width:180px;
  height:180px;
  margin: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  position:relative;
}

#tileHover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity:0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#tileHover:hover {
  opacity:1;
}

.tileText {
  font-size:18px;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:90%;
}

.tileSubText {
  font-size:12px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#tileType {
  width:180px;
  height:180px;
  background-color: #fdd108;
  margin: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  position:relative;
  
}

.tileType {
 position: absolute;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 margin-top: -12px;
 font-size:40px;
}

.tileType2 {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 margin-bottom: -8px;
 font-size: 25px;
 color:#fff;
}

.founder1 {
 background-image: url('');
 background-size: cover;
  background-color: green;
}

.founder2 {
 background-image: url('');
 background-size: cover;
  background-color: green;
}

.founder3 {
 background-image: url('');
 background-size: cover;
  background-color: green;
}

.employee1 {
 background-image: url('');
 background-size: cover;
  background-color: blue;
}

.employee2 {
 background-image: url('');
 background-size: cover;
  background-color: blue;
}

.employee3 {
 background-image: url('');
 background-size: cover;
  background-color: blue;
}

.employee4 {
 background-image: url('');
 background-size: cover;
  background-color: blue;
}

.employee5 {
 background-image: url('');
 background-size: cover;
  background-color: blue;
}

.employee6 {
 background-image: url('');
 background-size: cover;
  background-color: blue;
}

.employee7 {
 background-image: url('');
 background-size: cover;
  background-color: pink;
}

.employee8 {
 background-image: url('');
 background-size: cover;
  background-color: pink;
}

.employee9 {
 background-image: url('');
 background-size: cover;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="theTeamWrapper">
   
   <div id="megaWrapper">
    <div id="tileType">
     <h3 class="tileType">
     TEAM
            </h3>
      <h3 class="tileType2">
      A
            </h3>
     </div>
     
     <div id="tile" class="founder1">
      <div id="tileHover">
       <h3 class="tileText">
       NAME
       <br>
       <span class="tileSubText">Title</span>
            </h3>
        </div>
     </div>
     
     <div id="tile" class="founder2">
      <div id="tileHover">
       <h3 class="tileText">
       NAME
       <br>
       <span class="tileSubText">Title</span>
            </h3>
        </div>
     </div>

     <div id="tile" class="founder3">
      <div id="tileHover">
       <h3 class="tileText">
       NAME
       <br>
       <span class="tileSubText">Title</span>
            </h3>
        </div>
     </div>
     
     <div id="megaWrapper">
    <div id="tileType">
     <h3 class="tileType">
     TEAM
            </h3>
      <h3 class="tileType2">
      B
            </h3>
     </div>
     
     <div id="tile" class="employee1">
      <div id="tileHover">
       <h3 class="tileText">
       NAME
       <br>
       <span class="tileSubText">Title</span>
            </h3>
        </div>
     </div>
     
     <div id="tile" class="employee2">
      <div id="tileHover">
       <h3 class="tileText">
       NAME
       <br>
       <span class="tileSubText">Title</span>
            </h3>
        </div>
     </div>

     <div id="tile" class="employee3">
      <div id="tileHover">
       <h3 class="tileText">
       NAME
       <br>
       <span class="tileSubText">Title</span>
            </h3>
        </div>
     </div>
     
     <div id="tile" class="employee4">
      <div id="tileHover">
       <h3 class="tileText">
       NAME
       <br>
       <span class="tileSubText">Title</span>
            </h3>
        </div>
     </div>
     
     <div id="tile" class="employee5">
      <div id="tileHover">
       <h3 class="tileText">
       NAME
       <br>
       <span class="tileSubText">Title</span>
            </h3>
        </div>
     </div>
     
     <div id="tile" class="employee6">
      <div id="tileHover">
       <h3 class="tileText">
       NAME
       <br>
       <span class="tileSubText">Title</span>
            </h3>
        </div>
     </div>
     
     <div id="megaWrapper">
    <div id="tileType">
     <h3 class="tileType">
     TEAM
            </h3>
      <h3 class="tileType2">
      C
            </h3>
     </div>

     <div id="tile" class="employee7">
      <div id="tileHover">
       <h3 class="tileText">
       NAME
       <br>
       <span class="tileSubText">Title</span>
            </h3>
        </div>
     </div>
     
     <div id="tile" class="employee8">
      <div id="tileHover">
       <h3 class="tileText">
       NAME
       <br>
       <span class="tileSubText">Title</span>
            </h3>
        </div>
     </div>
     
     <div id="tile" class="employee9">
      <div id="tileHover">
       <h3 class="tileText">
       NAME
       <br>
       <span class="tileSubText">Title</span>
            </h3>
        </div>
     </div>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a Div that contains a lot of tiles, with names and Titles each one, and also some descriptive tiles such as "team1" "team2" and "team3"

Each Tile is 180x180px, I'm trying to achieve this with this responsive wrapper

[image]

There are 3 groups of tiles in colors, the Yellow describes that group as A, B or C. and once a tile moves down to another row because there's no more space I want it to brake that line and the next group to start under this one.

My code as a `https://jsfiddle.net/yw81cxzc/1/`

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You were missing some closing  tags for #megaWrapper which was making them close at the wrong locations and basically wrapping them around one another.  You can also remove justify-content: space-around; from #megaWrapper.  This should take care of everything unless you need it centered further.

```
#theTeamWrapper {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            background-image: url('https://www.kuboland.com/integra/images/bgTexture-01.png');
            background-size: cover;
            text-align: center;
            display: block;
            padding-top: 140px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }

        #megaWrapper {
            width: 90%;
            height: auto;
            background-color: ;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            align-content: flex-start;
            position: relative;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        #tile {
            width: 180px;
            height: 180px;
            margin: 20px;
            color: #fff;
            font-family: 'Montserrat';
            position: relative;
        }

        #tileHover {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        #tileHover:hover {
            opacity: 1;
        }

        .tileText {
            font-size: 18px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 90%;
        }

        .tileSubText {
            font-size: 12px;
            opacity: 0.8;
        }

        #tileType {
            width: 180px;
            height: 180px;
            background-color: #fdd108;
            margin: 20px;
            color: #fff;
            font-family: 'Montserrat';
            position: relative;
        }

        .tileType {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            margin-top: -12px;
            font-size: 40px;
        }

        .tileType2 {
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            margin-bottom: -8px;
            font-size: 25px;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .founder1 {
            background-image: url('');
            background-size: cover;
            background-color: green;
        }

        .founder2 {
            background-image: url('');
            background-size: cover;
            background-color: green;
        }

        .founder3 {
            background-image: url('');
            background-size: cover;
            background-color: green;
        }

        .employee1 {
            background-image: url('');
            background-size: cover;
            background-color: blue;
        }

        .employee2 {
            background-image: url('');
            background-size: cover;
            background-color: blue;
        }

        .employee3 {
            background-image: url('');
            background-size: cover;
            background-color: blue;
        }

        .employee4 {
            background-image: url('');
            background-size: cover;
            background-color: blue;
        }

        .employee5 {
            background-image: url('');
            background-size: cover;
            background-color: blue;
        }

        .employee6 {
            background-image: url('');
            background-size: cover;
            background-color: blue;
        }

        .employee7 {
            background-image: url('');
            background-size: cover;
            background-color: pink;
        }

        .employee8 {
            background-image: url('');
            background-size: cover;
            background-color: pink;
        }

        .employee9 {
            background-image: url('');
            background-size: cover;
            background-color: pink;
        }

<div id="theTeamWrapper">

        <div id="megaWrapper">
            <div id="tileType">
                <h3 class="tileType">
                    TEAM
                </h3>
                <h3 class="tileType2">
                    A
                </h3>
            </div>

            <div id="tile" class="founder1">
                <div id="tileHover">
                    <h3 class="tileText">
                        NAME
                        <br>
                        <span class="tileSubText">Title</span>
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="tile" class="founder2">
                <div id="tileHover">
                    <h3 class="tileText">
                        NAME
                        <br>
                        <span class="tileSubText">Title</span>
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="tile" class="founder3">
                <div id="tileHover">
                    <h3 class="tileText">
                        NAME
                        <br>
                        <span class="tileSubText">Title</span>
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="megaWrapper">
            <div id="tileType">
                <h3 class="tileType">
                    TEAM
                </h3>
                <h3 class="tileType2">
                    B
                </h3>
            </div>

            <div id="tile" class="employee1">
                <div id="tileHover">
                    <h3 class="tileText">
                        NAME
                        <br>
                        <span class="tileSubText">Title</span>
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="tile" class="employee2">
                <div id="tileHover">
                    <h3 class="tileText">
                        NAME
                        <br>
                        <span class="tileSubText">Title</span>
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="tile" class="employee3">
                <div id="tileHover">
                    <h3 class="tileText">
                        NAME
                        <br>
                        <span class="tileSubText">Title</span>
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="tile" class="employee4">
                <div id="tileHover">
                    <h3 class="tileText">
                        NAME
                        <br>
                        <span class="tileSubText">Title</span>
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="tile" class="employee5">
                <div id="tileHover">
                    <h3 class="tileText">
                        NAME
                        <br>
                        <span class="tileSubText">Title</span>
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="tile" class="employee6">
                <div id="tileHover">
                    <h3 class="tileText">
                        NAME
                        <br>
                        <span class="tileSubText">Title</span>
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="megaWrapper">
            <div id="tileType">
                <h3 class="tileType">
                    TEAM
                </h3>
                <h3 class="tileType2">
                    C
                </h3>
            </div>

            <div id="tile" class="employee7">
                <div id="tileHover">
                    <h3 class="tileText">
                        NAME
                        <br>
                        <span class="tileSubText">Title</span>
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="tile" class="employee8">
                <div id="tileHover">
                    <h3 class="tileText">
                        NAME
                        <br>
                        <span class="tileSubText">Title</span>
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="tile" class="employee9">
                <div id="tileHover">
                    <h3 class="tileText">
                        NAME
                        <br>
                        <span class="tileSubText">Title</span>
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot @wpalmes, is working really fine, somehow to align them to the middle? right now they're to the left corner of the main wrapper? with space-around shouldn't work?

Comment: I've done some digging, and it seems kind of tricky.  There were a lot of workarounds so to speak.  I guess an easy way would be to use space-around or space between (whichever fits properly), set a max-width on #mega-wrapper to keep the row to 4 items, and then use media-queries at each break point to reduce the row amount.  Not the best fix, but it may work.  You would still have the bottom row centered which would be another problem in itself.